# Do multiple Thunk dispatch execute synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

if I have 3 or 4 Thunk methods each having their own API requests. And i call them like:

```js
const someDummyThunkMethod = () => {
  return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>) => {

  dispatch(myFirstThunkWithAPICall());
  dispatch(mySecondThunkWithAPICall());
  dispatch(myThirdThunkWithAPICall());
  dispatch(myFourthThunkWithAPICall());
  }
}
```

Will all the 4 requests execute in parallel or in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

In parallel, since you're not `await`ing them. But they do get sent out in that order.

Comment: Cool. What if i have await in the respective methods. It wont have an impact right ? until i await it in the method mentioned above

Comment: No, that won't affect them. someDummyThunk is firing stuff off synchronously / parallel but what those functions do after they have been fired isn't handle by someDummyThunk.